# Using -finstrument-functions while building kernel for ARM

Tags: c, linux, gcc, linux-kernel, arm

How can we use [-finstrument-functions](http://gcc.activeventure.org/Code-Gen-Options.html) while building kernel for ARM. I mean how can we compile the kernel with **-finstrument-functions** such as `-funwind-tables`. Where do we find the option to add the options for code generation conventions? And also I want to know where `-pg` option is enabled while compiling kernel for debugging options.

Comment: I am really surprised that you are trying to do this and you don't know how to do that.

Comment: @IharobAlAsimi If you know the answer then please do let me know.

Comment: No, sadly I don't. But I really think you should read the Makefiles and infer all the information you need. Perhaps you are searching for `CFLAGS` and similar, but kernel Makefiles are a little kernelish and have specific conventions to allow the modules to compile either as modules or built into the kernel, and to enable/disable features. So you should google about kernel Makefiles and KBuild or something like that.